Using dynamic routing to access 404 in the production environment, but it can be accessed normally through the nuxt-link
Nuxt3 uses dynamic routing newsDetail/[id]. vue. The development environment is normal, and refreshing the page (F5) is also possible. However, after packaging through generate, there is no problem entering from the news list. When refreshing the page, it prompts 404. In addition, on the details page, after clicking to view the webpage source code, the page content contains the data returned from the backend. However, in the production environment, clicking to view the webpage source code displays the content of the static vue file packaged without backend data。
used generate.router look at the nuxt.config.ts
/pages
    news
    newsDetail
        [id].vue

enter image description here
nuxt.config
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
const path = require('path')
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  sourcemap: {
    server: false,
    client: false
  },
generate: {
    routes: ['/newsDetail/:id']
  },
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  css: ['~/assets/magic.min.css', '~/assets/main.scss'],
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: `@use '~/assets/base.scss' as *;`
        }
      }
    }
  },
  nitro: { minify: true, compressPublicAssets: true,
     output: {
    publicDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  }}
})


Page refresh (F5) can be accessed normally, and the webpage source code includes the data returned by the backend request

"the page content contains the data returned from the backend" - please, list it, it's unclear what happens on your side. And list what generated file structure looks like and which urls you use to access it, currently this can be done only on your side

Are you using any API call inside asyncData(ssr) in newsDetail/[id].vue?

List with parameters to newsDetail/11, go to the details page, and after obtaining the parameters on the details page, use usefetch to request the content of the article.
